# Pass Exposed Filter in Url / Link to Views page with AJAX

Tags: 8, views, ajax

I have a Views with page display of field sets on url

`www.foobar.com/specialview`

Contains a number of exposed filters *with* AJAX. - works great.

One of those fields I'm 'Rewrite Results' to a custom link.

That link is build with replacement patterns to form a url containing an argument for this same views page.

`www.foobar.com/specialview/?tid_1={{ field_area__target_id }}`

As a 'standard' link it works just fine and triggers the appropriate exposed filter, refreshes the page, updates url to drop the `/` to `www.foobar.com/specialview?tid_1={{ field_area__target_id }}`
That displays the active filter and results. - works great

However as soon as I add class `use-ajax` to the link ([as per D8 Ajax API doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x#sec_other)), the exposed filter is no longer actuated and the page results do not update, and obviously no page load. The exposed filters on the page still works via AJAX.

What am I missing to get AJAX working on my link on the same page, to the same page to trigger exposed filters in the url?

Comment: must add, that I'm wanting to do this through Views admin and not a custom module.